# Finding the standard matrix for orthogonal projection onto a subspace spanned by a given set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know if I'm on the right track in finding the matrix for the orthogonal projection onto a subspace, if I'm given the following vectors $(4, -6, 2, -4), (2, -3, 1, -2), (1, 0, -2, 5), (5, -6, 0, 1)$ that span the subspace.

So what I've done so far is create a matrix with the 4 vectors as row vectors (lets call it $A$). In order to find a basis for the column space, I took the transpose of $A$ and reduced it to reduced row echelon form and found 2 vectors that formed a basis for the rowspace of $A^T$. I then took the transpose of these two row vectors to get two columns that formed a basis for $A$, and from here I used these two column vectors for my matrix $M$ in the formula for the projection matrix

$P = M(M^T M)^{-1} M^T$.

Am I on the right track here?